# Opening a text file through Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a text file called and I want to import the contents of this file and then output it to a paragraph in HTML. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: you can read via FileReader API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) or use a standard ajax call to read file and display it

Comment: also you can read more abou File API to get insights into the file

Comment: Is the file on the client or server? You need to use AJAX to get files from the server.

Comment: This is on the client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `XMLHttpRequest`, like:

```
function World(){
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
  xhr.open('POST', 'hello_world.txt'); // change url accordingly
  xhr.onload = resp=>{
    document.getElementById('test').textContent = resp.responseText;
  }
  xhr.send();
}
```

Personally, I would get into the practice of separating HTML from JavaScript. So, if we got rid of `onload='World()` in your `<body>` tag and you use external JavaScript like your `test.js` page, it would be like:

```
let doc, bod, I; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', ()=>{ // same as your body load Event - everything deeper than load is indented
doc = docmuent; bod = doc.body; I = id=>doc.getElementById(id);
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.open('POST', 'hello_world.txt'); // change url accordingly
xhr.onload = resp=>{
  I('test').textContent = resp.responseText;
}
xhr.send();
}); // end load
```

Comment: It just says that XMLHttpReqest is not defined

Comment: Typo. It's `XMLHttpRequest`. Fixed.

Comment: Now it is saying that it is block by CORS policy?

Comment: So, the text is not on your Server?

Comment: Its just saved as a text file on my computer runing through the HTML file

Comment: The url I gave has `hello_world.txt` in your root folder on your Server, not your PC. Research absolute and relative paths.

Comment: You can't just read a text file off the Client's PC, without them uploading it with `<input type='file' />`, which you would use `Element.onchange = function(){ const files = this.files; if(files.length){ const file = files[0], fr = new FileReader; fr.onload = function(){ /* this.result  is response*/ } fr.readAsText(file); } }`.